# The input collected by my scanner is not being processed correctly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am trying, as a self-assigned exercise, to write a simple program that takes a birthday and determines the day of the week on which the given date falls. The first part of the program determines the year. I am using a scanner to collect the user input and then a do-while loop to test if the input is usable (must be a number, must have four digits) that repeats if the input does not fit the criteria. I am trying to enter the year 1998, which is obviously a number and four digits, and it repeats the loop as if my input is invalid. I assume there's a problem somewhere in my do-while loop, but I've been unable to determine what it is. Here is the code in question.

```
public static boolean isInteger(String input)
{
   try
   {
      Integer.parseInt(input);
      return true;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String year = "";
    String yearcorrect = "";
    int ylength = year.length();
    boolean yearIsYear = true;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do 
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the year of your birth.");
        year = scan.nextLine();
        boolean yearIsNum = isInteger(year);

        if (yearIsNum = false || ylength != 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Input is not a valid year.");
            yearIsYear = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You entered the year " + year + ". Is this correct?");
            yearIsYear = true;
            yearcorrect = System.console().readLine();
        }
    }
    while (yearcorrect != "yes" && yearIsYear != true);
```

Comment: `yearIsNum = false` means your `if` will never pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First mistake:**

```
    if (yearIsNum = false || ylength != 3)
```

it should be

```
    if (yearIsNum = false || ylength != 4)
```

**Second mistake:**

As @ChiefTwoPencils noted, `yearIsNum = false` will assign `false` to `yearIsNum` and the condition will never pass. Usually java protects us from such mistakes for all types except for... booleans. To avoid such errors in the future (and to make your code more readable) you can simply use `!yearIsNum` instead of `yearIsNum == false` or reverse the order of the values -> put the constant first: `false == yearIsNum` -> in this way if you miss `=` then the compiler will give you an error. Personally I prefer the `!yearIsNum` as it's shorter and more readable.

**Third mistake**

You are incorrectly comparing strings. You must use `str1.equals(str2)`. Using `==` for objects (and strings are objects) compares their references, not their values.

For instance `"a" == new String("a")` will be equal to `false`

Comment: There's also the problem of them not checking a boolean value but rather *assigning* it a false value which will negate the rest.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the points you and ChiefTwoPencils mentioned and it still didn't work, but when I moved "int ylength = year.length();" inside the do-while it worked.